# Ionic remove crosswalk not working

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I am using crosswalk with my Ionic application, but when I am trying to remove it, it always come back. I am using `ionic browser revert android` or `ionic browser remove crosswalk`, but when I am building my project for android after that I still get crosswalk running.

This is what I get from `ionic info`

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 15.10 
Node Version: v5.0.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: and trying with Cordova ($ cordova browser remove crosswalk) ?

Comment: I tried but I get this error `Error: Cordova does not know browser; try cordova help for a list of all the available commands.`

Comment: Try $ ionic state reset to remove everything and bring back what you have specified in your package.json

Comment: Thanks it almost works. I mean when I do this command I can build again without crosswalk. But when I am adding crosswalk, and want to remove it after, I still need to do `ionic state reset`... Do you know why ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is strange because the commands to remove the crosswalk are correct. They should work, and to me here works. Maybe your project is in trouble. You can try start from scratch a new project and to test. I did not find other questions talking about this issue then I suspect the problem is your Ionic or project. I hope that I have helped in some way.

Comment: Yes you are certainly right. I think the problem is coming from my project. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: I suggest to create a new ionic project and recreate the previous one...